# Copy array into ArrayList element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm using an arrayList that I'm adding entries from a database via a loop to. Within that loop, I fill an array with the fields from the row that I'm reading. I assign this array to the arrayList.

I understand from googling today that when I call arrayList.add() I'm passing a reference to the array instead of copying the array into the arrayList element. This is not what I want.

What's a better way to go about this?

```
    Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(Record.Records.CONTENT_URI, projection,       Record.Records.START_TIME + " > " + 1, null, Record.Records.START_TIME + " ASC");

    int i, n, x = 0;
    List<String[]> sleepCollection = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] sleepItem = new String[7];

    for (i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
    {
        if (i==0)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (n=0;n<5;n++)
            sleepItem[n] = cursor.getString(n);

        // hours, duration
        sleepItem[5] = String.valueOf((((Long.valueOf(sleepItem[1])-Long.valueOf(sleepItem[0]))/1000)+(Long.valueOf(sleepItem[4])*60))/60/60);
        // minutes, duration
        sleepItem[6] = String.valueOf((((Long.valueOf(sleepItem[1])-Long.valueOf(sleepItem[0]))/1000)+(Long.valueOf(sleepItem[4])*60))/60%60);

        if ( (x > 0) &&
             (Long.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[1]) - Long.valueOf(sleepItem[0]) <= 7200000) // record started within 2 hours if end of previous record 
           )
        {
            // set rating
            sleepCollection.get(x-1)[2] = String.valueOf((Float.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[2])) + Float.valueOf(sleepItem[2]) / 2);

            sleepCollection.get(x-1)[1] = sleepItem[1]; // set previous record's end date equal to current record's end date
            // then add duration of previous record to current record (hours, then minutes)
            sleepCollection.get(x-1)[5] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(sleepItem[5])+Integer.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[5]));
            sleepCollection.get(x-1)[6] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(sleepItem[6])+Integer.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[6]));
            // check if minutes are 60 or over
            if (Integer.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[6]) >= 60)
            {
                // if so, subtract 60 from minutes
                sleepCollection.get(x-1)[6] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[6]) - 60);
                // and add an hour to hours
                sleepCollection.get(x-1)[5] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(sleepCollection.get(x-1)[5]+1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // this passes a reference of sleepItem. I want sleepCollection to actually contain the array and not a reference to it. What's the best way to do that?
            sleepCollection.add(sleepItem);
            x++;
        }
```

Comment: Add a copy of `sleepItem` array.

Comment: Both answers given are correct. Marked the one as completed that I liked best. Turns out that I had a different bug in my code that made me discard the solution initially; I looked into it more deeply after ya'll confirmed that that's the right approach. Much appreciated, folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the gist of your problem

```
// This passes a reference of sleepItem. I want sleepCollection to 
// actually contain the array and not a reference to it.   What's 
// the best way to do that?
```

What you are asking does not (literally) make sense.  In Java, it does not sense to say that you want something to contain an array rather a reference to an array.  The array and the reference are fundamentally the same thing as far as the language is concerned.

(From a representational perspective, the "thing" that is in the `ArrayList` is always going to be a reference to an array.  The list uses a backing array which is an array of references.  It doesn't somehow internalize the argument array that you "add".)

---

Actually, what I think you are *really* asking is how to make each element in the list a reference to a *different* array.  The answer to that is to allocate a new array on each array iteration.  Or you could do this:

```
    sleepCollection.add(sleepItem.clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] sleepItem = new String[7];
```

must be moved to the loop inner, else entries of your arraylist will contain the same row data ;-).